# Segmentation fault when trying to execute recovered filesystem in a digital video tuner

Tags: linux, arm, embedded

Let me introduce where this thing comes from.
A few years ago I got a digital video tuner, which had a closed source version of Linux. The manufacturers of this device didn't want to share the source code of the OS, neither I was able to find it on internet. The SoC is a Celestial/Cavium CSM1800. 
Doing some dubious things, I accidentally executed the update procedure and wiped the NAND flash. Luckily, I had dumped the contents of the mtd partitions (there are 2 mapped to this NAND flash, Kernel 3M and the rest is a JFFS2 partition). 
This board has U-Boot loaded on another memory (a 1MB SPI), so "it wasn't totally bricked" because of the NAND wipe.

Back to the thing. I had a corrupt (dunno how it got corrupted) dump of the kernel, but after a lot of tinkering, I extracted the vmlinux (i.e. not gzip compressed) from the zImage. It seems the gzip unpack algorithm was bad, really weird.

After creating a new uImage using the vmlinux previously unpacked, I used the "fatload" command to load it and the thing booted, but of course it couldn't find the JFFS2 partition.

Then I tried writing the raw dump of the JFFS2 which I got from /dev/mtdblockX into the NAND, in the originally specified partition (after the 3M of the original kernel).
After booting, the kernel spit out a lot of errors concerning bad magics, empty flash, etc.

Well, after this I tried unpacking the JFFS2 in a Mint Virtual Machine, and I could extract the files. Since this tuner has an USB, I formatted a usb stick in ext2 and copied the files from the unpacked JFFS2 filesystem.
After crafting some bootargs to run from the usb stick instead of the NAND, I got the typical "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!".

I quickly tried to specify the sh command in init via the bootargs. Same thing. So I downloaded a static linked binary version of busybox. I copied it to the /bin/ (where the original one resided), marked as executable, and tried again. This time, I got a shell!

The thing is, when I try to run ANY of the original applications, I got a "Segmentation fault" and nothing else. 
Besides this, the /proc is not filled with anything, and I really don't have a clue why!
Other files, like text files or plain text files were OK, but im not discarding the possibility of a corrupted dump.

Finally, I tried to chroot to the unpacked JFFS2 in the Mint VM. Same "Segmentation fault" errors, but at least a core dump is created. I tried gdb-multiarch in that core dump, but only 2 frames appear, and since there are no symbols, nothing useful is shown there. (In fact, only the 2 frames addresses are only shown).

Some usefull (or not?) things:
binwalk of the vmlinux image

> 104288        0x19760         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC),
>   file name: "/dev", file name length: "0x00000005", file size:
>   "0x00000000"
>
> 104404        0x197D4         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC),
>   file name: "/dev/console", file name length: "0x0000000D", file size:
>   "0x00000000"
>
> 104528        0x19850         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC),
>   file name: "/root", file name length: "0x00000006", file size:
>   "0x00000000"
>
> 104644        0x198C4         ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC),
>   file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size:
>   "0x00000000"
>
> 1856733       0x1C54DD        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1284
>
> 1856853       0x1C5555        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1288
>
> 2597693       0x27A33D        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1292
>
> 2597797       0x27A3A5        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1292
>
> 2598317       0x27A5AD        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 5380
>
> 2598397       0x27A5FD        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 5380
>
> 3292029       0x323B7D        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1292
>
> 3292033       0x323B81        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1304
>
> 3292037       0x323B85        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 1308
>
> 3469469       0x34F09D        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3),
>   header length: 4, sequence length: 3
>
> 3701960       0x387CC8        Linux kernel version "2.6.32.36-SDK-1.1
>   (ylei@software) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-202) ) #7
>   PREEMPT Wed Feb 15 14:12:59 CST 2012"
>
> 3705492       0x388A94        gzip compressed data, maximum
>   compression, from Unix, last modified: 2012-01-18 04:15:11
>
> 3930268       0x3BF89C        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
>
> 4692111       0x47988F        Unix path:
>   /S70/S75/505V/F505/F707/F717/P8

readelf output of an executable file (rw_eeprom_byte). It's in spanish, but you could get the idea. http://pastebin.com/H0ZZcAaf (in pastebin so it keeps the spaces and it's more readeable).

uname:

> Linux (none) 2.6.32.36-SDK-1.1 #7 PREEMPT Wed Feb 15 14:12:59 CST 2012
>   armv5tejl GNU/Linux

Original boot (with the original filesystem and kernel):
http://pastebin.com/YL2d2HYj

Any hints? Maybe another firmware that has the same SoC where I can extract the filesystem?
Thanks!
PS1: English is not my native language, so forgive any errors you might see.
PS2: I'm not an expert in Linux, and my strong area is programming embedded devices (withouth linux :P).

Comment: The original vmlinux has an attached 'rootfs' which is a CPIO/ramfs.  It will have the original boot process.  `mount -t procfs proc proc` (or some such) will populate *proc*.  Your static busybox should have the `mount` command built in.  *mtdblock* is not a reliable way to read nand flash.  There are other tools (see http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/) for handling NAND flash which has bad blocks.

Comment: [*nanddump* and *nandwrite*](http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git/tree/HEAD:/nand-utils) are the way to go to get your JFFS.  Also, you need the original 'command line' that the system booted with.  Also, the *segfault* is probably due to the lack of a loader and shared libraries needed by the binaries.  You can use `readelf` or `objdump` on them to find out what libraries they want.  It is possible that your file system is partially corrupt and/or some other linux pseudo-fs needs to be mounted. (`cat /proc/filesystems`).

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks for your reply. The original boot argument was: 
bootargs=root=/dev/mtdblock4 rw rootfstype=jffs2 console=ttyS0,115200 mtdparts=csm_nand.0:3m(Kernel),-(fs). And it loaded linuxrc from the root "/linuxrc". This file was a symbolic link to busybox. 
I've tried to export the CPIO ramfs, but there weren't any files! Just 3 empty directories (/root /dev /dev/console).
The profile file had some init stuff, check it out http://pastebin.com/NsqUDSbZ. 
In my original post, I attached the output of readelf from a binary. The only libray (.so) exists! Anything else to do?

Comment: Just a small edit. I copied a inittab file from another "similar" DTV (in fact, it's another celestial/cavium, but quite different). Now I have /proc which is nice. I've tried to run the same apps again, and I have the same problem. This time it only says "SEGV" instead of the "segmentation fault". weird!
I've tried the root filesystem of the other DTV, and it works, but none of the tuner or DirectFB apps work (the DirectFB apps seems to have another library or a bad configured app; but the tuner app can't find the tuner IC, since its another board). T